# Extendable quick settings tile

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design-3, android-app-quick-setting

In Android 12L google added an extendable quick settings tile for internet(wifi and mobile data combined), for screen recorder, and for chromecast.
And my question is, can developers themselves create such quick settings tiles, or is it only the system tiles have such functionality?

I tried to read a Google's Android developer page about quick settings, But there is nothing about expandable tiles.

Comment: Did you try creating one and compare the behaviour on both Android versions ?

Comment: No, I haven't tried to create it yet, because I haven't found any documentation regarding the creation of it type of tile.

Comment: Try creating one and observe the different behaviour in Android 12 and Android 13.